# How Can I set up the preview Quality for objects I move in transformation mode in PS CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-quality, cc-2014

My question is easy.

I remember a function in an older version of Photoshop where I could say Photoshop to preview things I move around in lower quality to improve performance.

Where can I activate it in Photoshop CC? Or doesn't it exist anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using Photoshop for a long time and there's still features I don't know about or don't know well so this is certainly possible but I really don't think you're right. I'm guessing you're thinking of **InDesign** which has **Display Performance**:

[image]

In **Photoshop** you can do other things to improve performance such as Cache Options and Graphic Card settings and such. Two things you might consider are:

**Turning off animated zoom:** Open Photoshop → Preferences → General → Animated Zoom & Enable Flick Panning  → “Unchecked”

**Turn off Layer Thumbnails:** Open Photoshop → Layers Panel → Layers Panel Menu (dropdown) → Panel Options → “None”

[image]

Since the thumbnails have to constantly update as well this can really improve performance. But the sacrifice is no layer preview. Gotta be your choice. For more ways here's a good link:

[How To Optimize Photoshop For Better Performance](http://davidmckinney.com/blog/2014/1/1/designing-iphone-apps-how-to-optimize-performance-in-photoshop) by David McKinney